# Nothing works! jquery conflict magento

Tags: jquery-ui, magento

I am trying to use jquery UI based transition sliders on my homepage. I tried different jquery plugins but I always get an error in the console : jQuery is not a function or some function error related to jQuery . Plugins i have tried are Lof JSliderNews 1.0,featured-content-slider, etc..

Even after following several posts on the web , iam not able to make the plugin work at all. Jquery part doesn't work. I have used carousels and other plugins with jquery.noConflict but this time nothing works!

Here's what iam doing:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

I also tried replacing all $ with jQuery in the included scripts but that too doesn't work in magento. Please help, i need to finish the project soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting all the jQuery stuff into a function and map the `window.jQuery` variable as an argument? Like so:

```
(function($){
  //... do your jQuery thing here
})(jQuery);
```

**BTW**: "jQuery is not a function" might also be a hint that you forgot to load the jQuery library into your project.

Comment: It doesnt work! The plugin loads now but jquery function still does not work. Here is what i get in console TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function . Is there something I need to change in magento itself?

Comment: same thing as above i guess :-)   Did you load the jquery easing plugin? As I'm not familiar with magneto, I can't tell you if magneto is making trouble. Only thing I know is the jQuery-errors in the console (as I am quite familiar with errors ;-))

Comment: I resolved it. It was just that jquery was being called twice!! Such a dumb one, couldn't figure it out earlier

Comment: oh... too easy to find the mistake I guess  ;-)
  Glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "JS file merging" enabled? If yes, try to disable it, clear your cache and try again. It helped me once when I had a smiliar issue.

Regards